# Login e Senha com nível de permissão em php

Tags: php, pdo, login

Estou montado um sistema para facilitar a comunicação e o suporte aos representantes da empresa onde trabalho. O resto da página já existe, mas preciso fazer com que cada tipo de usuário seja direcionado para uma página diferente.

Um dos maiores problemas que estou enfrentando é que sempre aparece a mensagem de que o `mysql_connect` não funciona mais e que deve ser substituído pelo modo `PDO`.

Alguém aí consegue me ajudar?

Segue o código

```
<?php

// Verifica se houve POST e se o usuário ou a senha é(são) vazio(s)
if (!empty($_POST) AND (empty($_POST['usuario']) OR empty($_POST['senha']))) {
    header("Location: index.php"); exit;
}

// Tenta se conectar ao servidor MySQL
mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '') or trigger_error(mysql_error());
// Tenta se conectar a um banco de dados MySQL
mysqli_select_db('novosistema') or trigger_error(mysql_error());

$usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['senha']);

// Validação do usuário/senha digitados
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `nome`, `nivel` FROM `usuarios` WHERE (`usuario` = '". $usuario ."') AND (`senha` = '". sha1($senha) ."') AND (`ativo` = 1) LIMIT 1";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($query) != 1) {
    // Mensagem de erro quando os dados são inválidos e/ou o usuário não foi encontrado
    echo "Login inválido!"; exit;
} else {
    // Salva os dados encontados na variável $resultado
    $resultado = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

    // Se a sessão não existir, inicia uma
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();

    // Salva os dados encontrados na sessão
    $_SESSION['UsuarioID'] = $resultado['id'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioNome'] = $resultado['nome'];
    $_SESSION['UsuarioNivel'] = $resultado['nivel'];

    // Redireciona o visitante
    header("Location: restrito.php"); exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql

Comment: Se você estiver utilizando alguma versão do `PHP 5.5+` deve ter em mente que a biblioteca `mysql_*` foi descontinuada, deve-se procurar alternativas como citadas no link passado acima, como o `mysqli_*`, `PDO`, ou bibliotecas de outros frameworks

Answer (score 0):

> mysql_connect não funciona mais e que deve ser substituído pelo modo PDO.

Não devemos utilizar esta função mais, pelo simples fato do `PHP` possuir métodos mais sofisticados e mais seguros. além do mysql possuir limitações você pode usar a  `mysqli` que se trata de um método melhorado. no **stackoverflow** temos tópicos abordando esta questão:[Por que não devemos usar funcões do tipo mysql.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Neste mesmo link é explicado os beneficios da utilização da classe PDO.

Agora vamos falar um pouco sobre a lógica.
você precisa  redirecionar o usuario para uma página especifica  de acordo com o seu nivel de acesso. você pode simplesmente fazer uma verificação

```
se  sessãonivel == administrador então acesse pagina x
se  sessãonivel == cliente entao acesse pagina y.
```

crie uma função que  verifique se o usuario x esta acessando a pagina y e redirecione para a pagina correta.

Answer (score 0):

Cara Sugiro que atualize o acesso com a biblioteca `PDO`, que é muito mais fácil e mais segura.
Caso você seja acostumado a programar `PHP OO`, utilize classes para receber os valores das `$_SESSION`.

Segue um exemplo que utilizei para validação de login com `PDO`

```
<?php
// Conexão Com o banco de dados
// INCLUI A CLASSE PARA CONEXÃO COM BANCO DE DADOS
    function __autoload($classe){
        if(file_exists("pdo/{$classe}.class.php")){
            require_once "pdo/{$classe}.class.php";
        }
    }

// Inicia sessões
session_start();

// Recupera o login
$login = isset($_POST["login"]) ? (trim($_POST["login"])) : FALSE;
// Recupera a senha, a criptografando em MD5
$senha = isset($_POST["senha"]) ? md5(trim($_POST["senha"])) : FALSE;

// Usuário não forneceu a senha ou o login
    if(!$login || !$senha){  
        header("Location: erro_login.php");
    exit;
    }

$Consulta_Login     =   "SELECT id, nome, sobre_nome, data_nascimento, senha, resgata_senha, email, estado, cidade, iurd
                            FROM login_usuario
                        WHERE email = '" . $login . "'";

        $PDO    =   ConexaoBanco::open();
        $result =   $PDO->query($Consulta_Login);

        if($result->rowCount()){
            $linhas = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            if(!strcmp($senha, $linhas->senha)){
                $_SESSION["id_login_usuario"]   =   $linhas->id;
                $_SESSION["confirma_cadastro"]  =   "0";

                    switch ($linhas->nome) {    

                        default;
                            //header("Location: loading.html");
                            header("Location: loading.php");
                        break;

                    }
                    exit;
            }else{
                // Senha inválida
                    header("Location: erro_login.php");
                exit;
            }

        }else{
            //Login Invalido
                header("Location: erro_login.php");
            exit;
        }   

        $PDO    =   null;


?>
```

Com Relação ao nível de acesso, existem diversas formas, já que você inseriu um campo nível no banco, como um `Switch` para ter ações de acordo com os niveis.